# Using Patched Method to get called arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

I was doing some unit testing against database calls, I was essentially doing a patch for cursors.  The issue I was having is that I want to patch the return variable but also check what the arguments are in order to ensure they are valid.

Is this possible?  I was going through the documents but didnt anything other than `side_effect` and `return_value`.

I mostly was flipping through the docs at: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html

Since patch is a wrapper for mock, when looking at the Mock class, I was thinking there might be something else there which could prove useful.

Answer (score 0):

The class Mock class, you can see a property called `call_args` which returns the most recently called arguments, it returns a call type.

```
call(1,2,3,4)
```

But you can also access the arguments to be addressed directly by referencing `args`.

```
from test import func
with patch("some.func") as fn:
    fn.return_value = "hello world"
    func(1,2,3,4)
    tuple_of_args = fn.call_args.args
    print(tuple_of_args)
```